# Popup if the Alternate Version of a Site is Shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I've look around but can't find anything that suits my needs. I have a site and a CSS media query is used. If a screen is LESS than 1100px, a different version of the site is displayed and not the full version.

I'd like a popup to be displayed shortly after the page has loaded saying "You are viewing the alternate version of this website" when the user is on a screen LESS than 1100px. I do NOT want the user to see this popup if they are viewing the full site.

I'm sorry I have no code to show you!

JavaScript or jQuery if possible please.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `I'm sorry I have no code to show you!` - no good...

Comment: @Ian Thanks for that amazing response. Why is code always needed. I have no idea what to write, I thought this site was helpful...

Comment: @Chris - do you know how to display a popup?  do you know how to detect the width of a web browser?  what part of this are you actually stuck on? you've presented a problem with multiple parts without showing work on any one of them.

Comment: @SamDufel No, I don't know how to do any of it, that's why I'm asking!

Comment: @Chris This site **is** helpful. But it isn't a **code generation tool**. You come to this site with a specific **code** problem and get help. You don't come asking for someone to fully create/solve something you want. You haven't even shown that you've tried anything, including researching the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
var width = $(window).width();

if (width < 1100) {
 alert("You are viewing an alternate theme");
}

});
```

Don't forget to include jquery in the header of your html document.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually perfect. One more thing. Is there a way to get it to be displayed only once, just when the page is loaded for the first time?

Comment: It should only display once by default based on the code I gave you. Unless you added that code to a function and call that function every time the page is resized. If you post your code I may be able to determine the problem.

Comment: Oh, that's strange. I copied the code and it shows the popup every time I load the page. The code I'd provide would only be the code you gave me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself. Yes, it displays once but I mean can it be that it's shown once and they go to another page but they return to the page that has the popup but this time is ISN'T displayed?

Comment: Ahh now I see what you're trying to do. I would use a cookie for this.  When the page loads check if a cookie has been set and if a cookie has not been set, set one as well as present the popup. If the cookie has been set, do nothing. If you don't know how to use a cookie w3schools explains how to use cookies in JS. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp